# Double rows for the same country when importing WDI data in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R. Trying to import data from WDI for 5 countries from 1980 to 2020, I get 74 rows (years) for each country where I expect 41. The pattern I can see is that for each country there are data from 1980 to 2012 which are all NA and have 3-digit country names, and there are data from 1980 to 2020 with some values having 2-digit country names. Why is this happening and how can I tackle it without having to delete the excess rows of data? I appreciate your help!

```
Main_dataset <- WDI(indicator = 
                      c("BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS","NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG", "NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS",
                        "FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG","SP.POP.GROW","NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD",
                        "SE.PRM.NENR","SP.DYN.LE00.FE.IN","IT.NET.BBND.P2",
                        "GE.EST","DT.ODA.ODAT.GN.ZS", "IS.ROD.PAVE.ZS"), 
                    country = c("ZW","MZ","MG","TZ","RW"), start = 1980, end = 2020, extra = FALSE)
```

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/WDI/issues/54

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it was stemming from "IS.ROD.PAVE.ZS" indicator and after deleting it, the issue was resolved.